# How to put a hat on a binary operator and maintain spacing

Tags: math-mode, spacing, math-operators

This is maybe easy question.
How is the right/good way to put a hat on a binary operator like `\otimes`?
For example `a\otimes b` vs `a\hat\otimes b` 
In the second case it is not typeset as a binary operator anymore, i.e. missing spaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `a\mathbin{\hat\otimes}b` to retrieve the original spacing of a binary operator:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$a\otimes b \quad a\hat\otimes b \quad a\mathbin{\hat\otimes}b$
\end{document}​
```